# Why is this regular expression only capturing the last digit?

Tags: python, regex

From my code it should be pretty easy to see what I'm trying to do

```
for path in glob.glob("orig_data/*.*"):
    pattern = ".*(\d+\.).*"
    new_name = re.sub(pattern, r'\1txt', path)
    copyfile(path, 'orig_data_renamed/'+new_name)
```

I just want to keep the numbers that are immediately before the "." filename but it's not having it.

Here's an example output

```
some_folder/asdf321428.txt
8.txt
```

The problem is clearly with the '+' but I'm not sure what it wants instead.

Comment: Try `.*?(\d+\.).*` instead. `.*` matches greedily.

Comment: I still get the same result. In the above, I'd like for the new to pop out as '321428.txt'

Comment: @financial_physician Is your expected output `321428`, or is it `321428.txt` ?

Comment: the latter, but it's really easy to get their from your answer below. Out of curiosity, what does "r" do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `re.sub` solution, also using string split.  We can split the input path on separator `/`, and then use the last element to obtain the numbers.  We make a second call to `re.sub` to isolate the digits occurring just before the dot.

```
path = "some_folder/asdf321428.txt"
nums = re.sub(r'^.*?(\d+)\.\w+$', '\\1', path.split("/")[-1])
print(nums)
```

This prints:

```
321428
```

If you just want the filename, then try this version:

```
path = "some_folder/asdf321428.txt"
nums = re.sub(r'^.*?(?=\d+\.\w+$)$', '', path.split("/")[-1])
print(nums)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

```
(\S*?)(\d*)\.txt
```

might work OK here.

#### Test

```
import re

string = '''
some_folder/asdf321428.txt
8.txt
some_folder123/asdf321428.txt
'''

expression = r'(?m)(\S*?)(\d*)\.txt'


print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
[('some_folder/asdf', '321428'), ('', '8'), ('some_folder123/asdf', '321428')]
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1etIOj/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/1etIOj/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: For some reason, when I run yours I still get errors. Tim's works for me. I don't know why yours doesn't work for me. It looks good on the regex101.com page

Answer (score 1):

You're saying you want to **keep** the numbers, but what you're doing with `re.sub` is **substituting** the numbers. What you want to do is: find by the pattern, then take the first match (please handle error by yourself)

```
new_name = re.findall(pattern, path)[0]  + "txt"
```

Output:

```
321428.txt
```

also if you want to take *all* the digits before the dot, simply change the pattern into:

```
pattern = r"\D(\d+\.)"
```

Comment: Thank you! This fills me in on a lot